# How To Have 3 Divs Change Image Every Second From Its Own Folder?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, html

I want to have 3 divs that changes its image every second.This code doesnt call any errors but the only one that is working is the 3rd div with source of script9.js. Why is this happening? Please help... Here it is:

I have 3 dives that contain images from there own folder:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="mainjavascript.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script8.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script9.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload = "startTimer()">

  <div><img id="img" src="pictures7/1.jpg">7</div>
  <div><img id="img2" src="pictures8/1.jpg">8</div>
  <div><img id="img3" src="pictures9/1.jpg">9</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have 3 similar JavaScript files, one for each div that gets element by ID the only difference is in "** **" signs:

```
 function displayImage(image) {
          document.getElementById(**"img"**).src = image;
      }

      function displayNextImage() {
          x = (x == images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
          displayImage(images[x]);           
      }

      function displayPreviousImage() {
          x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
          displayImage(images[x]);           
      }

      function startTimer() {
          setInterval(displayNextImage, 1000);
      }

      var images = [], x = -1;
      images[0] = **"pictures7/"** + "1.jpg";
      images[1] = **"pictures7/"** + "2.jpg";
      for(var y=2;y<4;y++){
      images[y]= **"pictures7/"** + (y+1) + ".jpg";
      }
```

2nd div:

```
 function displayImage(image) {
          document.getElementById(**"img2"**).src = image;
      }

      function displayNextImage() {
          x = (x == images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
          displayImage(images[x]);           
      }

      function displayPreviousImage() {
          x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
          displayImage(images[x]);           
      }

      function startTimer() {
          setInterval(displayNextImage, 1000);
      }

      var images = [], x = -1;
      images[0] = **"pictures8/"** + "1.jpg";
      images[1] = **"pictures8/"** + "2.jpg";
      for(var y=2;y<4;y++){
      images[y]= **"pictures8/"** + (y+1) + ".jpg";
      }
```

3rd Div:

```
 function displayImage(image) {
          document.getElementById(**"img3"**).src = image;
      }

      function displayNextImage() {
          x = (x == images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
          displayImage(images[x]);           
      }

      function displayPreviousImage() {
          x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
          displayImage(images[x]);           
      }

      function startTimer() {
          setInterval(displayNextImage, 1000);
      }

      var images = [], x = -1;
      images[0] = **"pictures9/"** + "1.jpg";
      images[1] = **"pictures9/"** + "2.jpg";
      for(var y=2;y<4;y++){
      images[y]= **"pictures9/"** + (y+1) + ".jpg";
      }
```

Again, Only the image with id of "img3.jpg" is working... is it canceling the other code?
should i use Jquery or some other code? Please help me.

Comment: You are repeating the same functions. You should be using one set of functions ans passing them image folder paths as variables.

Answer (score 1):

You're repeating the same function definitions several times; give them different names.

Comment: can you give me an example? ive been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: that is all the js i have. how can i not repeat the same funtions?

Answer (score 1):

You have the same functions declared in three files. However, the functions themselves are all created in the global scope so each JS file is overwriting the previous one. You can validate this using the developer console in Chrome.

You want to keep your code DRY - Don't repeat yourself. So try to rewrite this with only one function that runs on the page load and consolidate the remaining three files into one.

Comment: how do i make these functions different so it can work. im new to this im a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

This whipped this one up this just loops through an array and if it tries to go further than the array then it resets to the first image

```
var images = ['create an array of pictures']
var currentimage = 0;

function loop() {
 currentimage++;

if(currentimage > images.length){
 currentimage = 0;
}
 setimage();
}

function setImage() {
    document.getElementById('image').src = images[currentImage];
}

setInterval(loop, 1000);
```